# Webkit transition not synced

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm currently working on a page flip effect in CSS. I've managed to do something quite convincing but I have a problem with webkit based browsers

Test this link with chrome and firefox and you will see the problem :

http://jsfiddle.net/et4ZQ/29/

**HTML**

```
<div id="page-flip" class="animate">
    <div id="frontface">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="shadow">PAGE 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="investigation-container">
        <div class="span12">
        PAGE 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="backface">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="shadow"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" style="color:#FFF; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:500;" onclick='$("#page-flip").toggleClass("turn"); return false;'>Toggle page turn</a>
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'fineliner_scriptregular';
    src: url('http://cthulhu.byook.com/fonts/fineliner_script-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://cthulhu.byook.com/fonts/fineliner_script-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://cthulhu.byook.com/fonts/fineliner_script-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://cthulhu.byook.com/fonts/fineliner_script-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://cthulhu.byook.com/fonts/fineliner_script-webfont.svg#fineliner_scriptregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family:'AgencyFBRegular';
    src: url('http://cthulhu.byook.com/fonts/agency_fb.eot');
    src: url('http://cthulhu.byook.com/fonts/agency_fb.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://cthulhu.byook.com/fonts/agency_fb.woff') format('woff'), url('http://cthulhu.byook.com/fonts/agency_fb.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://cthulhu.byook.com/fonts/agency_fb.svg#AgencyFBRegular') format('svg');
}

body, html {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
    max-height:480px;
    width:320px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#000;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#investigation, .investigation-dummy {
    margin-top:120px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:12;
}
#inv_content, .text-dummy {
    width:90%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-family:"Advent Pro";
    font-size:12pt;
}

/* ANIMATIONS
 * PAGE FLIP
 */
 #page-flip {
    width:320px;
    height:100%;
    max-height:568px;
}
#page-flip #frontface {
    /*display:none;*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 75;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 350px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -350px, 0px) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0px 350px;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, -350px, 0px) rotate(45deg);
}
#page-flip.animate #frontface {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, -moz-transform-origin;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}
#page-flip.turn #frontface {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 530px 160px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-530px, -160px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 530px 160px;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-530px, -160px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
}
#page-flip #frontface .page {
    width: 530px;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#page-flip #frontface .page > .content {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 350px, 0px) rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 350px, 0px) rotate(-45deg);
    background-image:url(http://cthulhu.byook.com/img/investigation/bg_investigation@2x.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom center;
    background-size:cover;
    width: 320px;
    height:480px;
}
#page-flip.animate #frontface .page > .content {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, -moz-transform-origin;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}
#page-flip.turn #frontface .page > .content {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(530px, 160px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(530px, 160px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
}
#page-flip #frontface .page > .content > .shadow {
    width: 10px;
    height:480px;
    max-height:568px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    background: -moz-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}
#page-flip .investigation-container {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 320px;
    background-image:url(http://cthulhu.byook.com/img/investigation/bg_investigation@2x.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom center;
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
    max-height:480px;
    font-size:9pt;
}
#page-flip #backface {
    /*display:none;*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 75;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 350px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -350px, 0px) rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0px 350px;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, -350px, 0px) rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
#page-flip.animate #backface {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, -moz-transform-origin;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}
#page-flip.turn #backface {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 530px 160px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-530px, -160px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 530px 160px;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-530px, -160px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
}
#page-flip #backface .page {
    width: 530px;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#page-flip #backface .page > .content {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 480px 280px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(495px, 375px, 0px) rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -moz-transform-origin: 480px 280px;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(495px, 375px, 0px) rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    width: 320px;
    height:480px;
    background-image:url(http://cthulhu.byook.com/img/investigation/bg_investigation@2x.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom center;
    background-size:cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#page-flip.animate #backface .page > .content {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, -moz-transform-origin;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}
#page-flip.turn #backface .page > .content {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 300px 280px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(210px, 160px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 300px 280px;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(210px, 160px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
}
#page-flip #backface .page > .content > .shadow {
    width: 9px;
    height:480px;
    max-height:568px;
    float: right;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .20)));
    background: -moz-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .20)));
}
```

Transitions are not synced with webkit witch cause the page being hidden (#frontface .page .content) to figit around. I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to prevent this behavior and have nice and clean transition like in firefox ? Keep in mind that it's ultimately designed to be on iOS ...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Just looking at your CSS you have way more code than you need to. Do you want it to flip horizontally or vertically? (sorry I don't have firefox and you didn't say which it was in the question)

Comment: I want it to flip horizontally but I want it to look like a fluid page turn. How can I do it with less code ?

Comment: [Turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/docs/8) which I reccomend, [this example](http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/docs/8), [something like this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-page-flip-effect), or something else depending on what you're looking for. There are a lot of examples if you look

Comment: I know turn.js but it's not running smoothly on an ios device and it's not free to use, and my exemple is based on the css3 page flip effect you gave me, and if you look closely it has the same problem as I do ...